# Pig Latin Translator in java not working?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a pig latin translator and it seems as if it gets stuck in the loop and doesn't ever come out of it. Can someone help?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String textread = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\fedte\\IdeaProjects\\PIg Latin\\src\\trial.txt")).useDelimiter("\\z").next();

        String[] pig_latin_words = textread.split(" ");
        ArrayList<String> translated = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < pig_latin_words.length; i++)
        {
            String pig_latin_word = pig_latin_words[i];
            char letter1 = pig_latin_word.charAt(0);
            letter1 = Character.toLowerCase(letter1);

            if (letter1 == ('a') || letter1 == ('e') || letter1 == ('i') || letter1 == ('o') || letter1 == ('u'))
            {
                pig_latin_word = pig_latin_word+"yay";
                translated.add(pig_latin_word);

            }
            else
            {
                do
                {
                    pig_latin_word = pig_latin_word.substring(1) + pig_latin_word.substring(0, 1);
                    letter1 = pig_latin_word.charAt(0);
                    letter1 = Character.toLowerCase(letter1);
                } while (letter1 != ('a') && letter1 != ('e') && letter1 != ('i') && letter1 != ('o') && letter1 != ('u'));
                pig_latin_word = pig_latin_word+"yay";
                translated.add(pig_latin_word);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(translated);
    }
}
```

Comment: What input is in your file?  When I run your code against the string "this is a test", I get the output `[isthyay, isyay, ayay, esttyay]` immediately.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that would cause an infinite loop is if a word has no vowels, it'll look forever trying to find the first one.

Comment: @azurefrog And since they are only treating AEIOU as vowels, completely valid words like "sky" or "crypt" will end up getting stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: @Jordan *Why*, you have a good eye. ;-) I overlooked the missing Y vowel; I bet that's it.

Comment: @Jordan Omg thank you so much, it was because of the fact that Y is not included because I was inputting the word "my" and so it didnt know what to do with it.